# How to find expected value of a portion of the normal distribution?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, problem-solving, expectation

$X\sim N(67,4)$

What's the expected value of the portion of the curve $(X>72)$?

I tried to use the definition of expected value ($\int xf(x) \mathrm{d}x$), but my integral was far too complicated and when I tried to evaluate using WolframAlpha the answer was nonsensical...

How do I set up this problem?

Comment: Do you want to calculate $E(X|X>72)$? The final answer will still involve $\Phi(x)$, where $\Phi$ is the cdf of standard normal distribution.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm after... I've never calculated a conditional expected value like that before, it is like calculating for a standard probability? Do Bayes' rule and other ways to calculate conditional probabilities apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Notations:** Let $F$ and $f$ be the cdf and pdf of $X$ respectively. Let $\Phi$ and $\phi$ be the cdf and pdf of a standard normal variable.

**Part 1: Justification**

First of all can you calculate $P(a<X<b|X>72)$?

Yes you can! It is $\displaystyle \frac{P(a<X<b \cap X>72)}{P(X>72)}$.

Now you can treat $Y:=X|X>72$ as a random variable whose pdf (if exists) you would like to compute. First let us calculate the cdf (say $G(a)$).

$$G(a)=P(X\le a|X>72) =\frac{P(X\le a \cap X>72)}{P(X>72)}$$
Now make two cases. If $a\le 72$, then $X\le a \cap X>72 =\emptyset$. And if $a>72$, 
$$P(X\le a \cap X>72)=P(72<X\le a)=P(X\le a)-P(X\le 72)=F(a)-F(72)$$
Conclusion
$$G(a)=\begin{cases}\frac{F(a)-F(72)}{P(X>72)} & a>72\\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Hence this random variable $Y$ admits a pdf $g$ given by
$$g(a)=\begin{cases}\frac{f(a)}{P(X>72)} & a>72\\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

**Part 2: Calculation**

$$\begin{aligned} & E(X|X>72) =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xg(x)\,dx \\ & = \frac1{P(X>72)}\int_{72}^{\infty} x\frac1{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac12\left(\frac{x-67}{2}\right)^2\right)\,dx \\ & = 
\frac{\int\limits_{72}^{\infty} \frac{x-67}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac12\left(\frac{x-67}{2}\right)^2\right)\,dx+67\int\limits_{72}^{\infty}\frac1{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac12\left(\frac{x-67}{2}\right)^2\right)\,dx}{P(X>72)} \\ & = \frac1{P(X>72)}\int\limits_{\frac{(2.5)^2}2}^{\infty} 2\exp(-t)\,dt +67 \\ & =67+\frac{2e^{-\frac{(2.5)^2}2}}{1-\Phi(2.5)}  \end{aligned}$$
In the third line $\frac12\left(\frac{x-67}{2}\right)^2=t$ substitution was used. There may computational mistakes, but the trick is essentially present above.

**Part 3: Approximation**

You can use the following fact
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1-\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)/x}=1$$
Hence for large enough $x$, $1-\Phi(x) \approx \frac{\phi(x)}{x}$. Replacing this in the dinominator of the last answer, gives a good approximation.

Comment: In the second line, why did you break up $x$ into $x-67$ and $67$? Is it so you can have another substitution for $t$ in the third line?

Comment: Also, just to be sure  I understand, if you have $E(X|Y)$, then it can be rewritten as $\frac{E(X)}{P(Y)}$?

Comment: Yes, for substitution that breaking was necessary.
 $E(X|Y)=E(X)/P(Y)?$. That's a big statement, depending on whether $Y$ is a event, or a random variable. I will try to give a proper justification of that thing tommorrow.

Comment: @pocketlizard you may have a look at the edited version of the solution.

Comment: This is great - very clear! Each step has a very logical progression.